# JS: promp thet user for input, until they enter a valid value specified in parameter

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement, do-while

My script is supposed to prompt the user to enter a gender, if the gender is either 'M' or 'F' then it will return. If any other input, then it must continue to prompt until either value is entered.

```
function getGender() {
    var yourGender = prompt('Enter your gender (M / F)');
    var choice = yourGender;

if (choice = 'M' || 'F') {
    return choice;
} else
    do {
        var yourGender = prompt('Enter your gender (M / F)');
    }
    while (choice != 'M' || 'F') {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `do-while` loop is not the same as a `while` loop, it looks like you are confusing their syntax. Here is an example of its usage from the MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while

Also, when checking true or false with logical operators, you must check the variable against each condition. Your function should be much simpler:

```
function getGender() {
  do {
    var yourGender = prompt('Enter your gender (M / F)').toLowerCase();
  } while (yourGender !== 'm' && yourGender !== 'f');

  return yourGender;
}
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Yes, it should have been more simplistic, appreciate the help. Do you know how to make the prompt case insensitive? i.e toLowerCase?

Comment: @JimmieDavis Sure, I've updated the answer with `.toLowerCase()`. You just have to add it on to the end of the prompt, and then change the conditional check for lowercase 'm' and 'f'.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getGender()
{
    var yourGender; //otherwise, 'while' doesn't know it
    do
    {
        yourGender = prompt('Enter your gener (M/F)');
    } 
    while(yourGender != 'M' && yourGender != 'F')
}
```

I got no idea if the prompt part is correct but do-while part should work like this.

Comment: Do you know how to make the prompt case insensitive? i.e toLowerCase?

Comment: just add && yourGender != 'm'  && yourGender != 'f' in the if

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getGender(sensitive){
  let gender;
  let pat = sensitive ? /[MF]/ : /[MF]/i;
  do
  {
    gender = prompt("Enter your gender (M / F)", '');
  } while( !gender.match(pat) );
  return gender;
}

/* Case sensitive
getGender(sensitive=true);
//*/

//* Not case sensitive
getGender(sensitive=false);
//*/
```

Comment: Do you know how to make the prompt case insensitive? i.e toLowerCase?